Swift 6, 'image' causes data races?
I have an image picker struct that I use to take and store photos as a list however with Swift 6 strict concurrancy I can't for the life of me get it to work.
This is the original struct
struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ImagePickerView

        init(_ parent: ImagePickerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Handle image picker for camera capture
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) {
                    parent.imageList.append(ImageData(
                        _id: "\(UUID())",
                        imageData: imageData
                    ))
                }
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }

        // Handle picker for selecting from library
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)

            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let imageData = (image as? UIImage)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) {
                            self.parent.imageList.append(ImageData(
                                _id: "\(UUID())",
                                imageData: imageData
                            ))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Binding var imageList: [ImageData]
    @Binding var isCamera: Bool

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        if isCamera {
            // Camera access using UIImagePickerController
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
            return imagePicker
        } else {
            // Photo Library using PHPickerViewController
            var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
            config.selectionLimit = 1
            config.filter = .images

            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator
            return picker
        }
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}

Within the picker function, the if let imageData = (image as? UIImage)?, the image is flagged with,
Sending 'image' risks causing data races.
Task-isolated 'image' is captured by a main actor-isolated closure. main actor-isolated uses in closure may race against later nonisolated uses.
I'm struggling to understand how to fix this error, I've attempted to run the dispatchQueue as a Task { @MainActor in } but that leads to the self.parent saying that sending self causes data races.

You can add “preconcurrency” to the UIKit import. On this file, then report to Apple. They will likely make it safe eventually. Also note than in Swift 6 using GCD will be a thing of the past the new concurrency is much safer

you can't do Coordinator(self), the representable is a struct not a class, i.e. not a reference type, its a value so self is immediately out of date because in SwiftUI the structs are recreated all the time in body. You need to implement updateUIViewController to use the new property values to update the coordinator and the view controller.

You are trying to solve Swift concurrency isolation problems with GCD, which is generally not a good idea.
The loadObject completion handler requires Sendable conformance since it can be passed across concurrency domains. This also means that all captured values must conform to Sendable.
See SE-0302 for more details.
Your Coordinator is already bound to the MainActor by the way it is declared and through the protocol conformances. This means that Coordinator already conforms to Sendable.
So you don't have to do anything in this regard. All you have to do is adjust the call in the completion handler:
// Handle picker for selecting from library
func picker(
    _ picker: PHPickerViewController,
    didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]
) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)

    guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider, provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) else {
        return
    }

    provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
        guard let imageData = (image as? UIImage)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) else {
            return
        }

        Task { @MainActor in
            self.parent.imageList.append(ImageData(
                _id: UUID().uuidString,
                imageData: imageData
            ))
        }
    }
}

Note that this captures self in the completion handler and the task in it.
If you want to prevent this or have a cancel mechanism, you must add this accordingly. However, this was not part of your actual question, so I won't go into it in detail.

Thank you for the assistance, that did fix the issue. I'm still trying to understand this whole concurrency system. Is using Task more preferred over using DispatchQueue? I frequently reference DispatchQueue and only have just started using Task as I've been working through updating my app to Swift 6.

In this particular case, it is less a preference than a necessity to use the tools and resources of Swift Concurrency. The moment something requires conformance to Sendable you are in the world of Swift concurrency and shouldn't try to use GCD. GCD and structured concurrency differ significantly in how they work. E.g. calling a closure via DispatchQueue.main is not the same as executing a Task on the MainActor. For the basics, Apple has provided many WWDC videos on structured concurrency over the past few years that I would recommend watching.
